# CSS regex inside selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am trying to apply some rules on a set of img elements whose id begins with "sth". I know how to select them:

```
img [id^=sth]
```

But is there a way to use this image specific id inside the selector? In other words, can I somehow do this:

```
img [id^=sth] {
    src: id;
}
```

Comment: [May or may not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/attr). But anyway, `src` is not a valid CSS property of `<img>`, so I don't think your specified example can work.

Comment: Ok, this was just for example purposes, what I need is to use the id as a part of the name of an image.

Comment: `src`, `name`, `title`, `alt` are all not valid CSS property of `<img>` (`name` is even an obsoleted HTML attribute as of HTML5), so there's really not much you can do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that with css but you can use jQuery:

```
$("div[id^='sph']").each(function() {
    $(this).attr("src", this.id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only use an attributes value in a pseudo element `:before` or `:after` via the `content` attribute:

```
div:after{
content:attr(id);
}
```

Comment: Indeed - you cannot write to an element's attribute using CSS, you can only read from it and use it for generating content.